# Update Item in DynamoDB from CLI

Tags: dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb

I try to update one item from DynamoDb CLI but I am getting error

```
aws dynamodb update-item \
    --table-name test \
    --key '{"testid": {"S": "testing"}}' \
    --update-expression "SET userType = :ut" \
    --expression-attribute-values  '{":ut":{"L":[{"S":"PRIMARY"},{"S":"SECONDRY"}]}}' \
    --return-values ALL_NEW
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @jellycsc syntax error

Comment: Error Unknown options: testing}}', {S:

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing single quotes (') to double quotes (") and double quotes(") to backslash double quotes ("). Some terminals may not process single quotes correctly.

```
aws dynamodb update-item \
--table-name test \
--key "{\"testid\": {\"S\": \"testing\"}}" \
--update-expression "SET userType = :ut" \
--expression-attribute-values  "{\":ut\":{\"L\":[{\"S\":\"PRIMARY\"},{\"S\":\"SECONDRY\"}]}}" \
--return-values ALL_NEW
```